# Load module based on canLoad at runtime

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-guards

#### Context

I have a basic administration page, that has two implementations, depending on a parameter in the server.

Here is the configuration I'm using for the router:

```
      {
        path: 'projects',
        loadChildren: 'app/...#ProjectsAModule',
        canLoad: [PluginGuard],
        data: {
          requiredPlugins: ['foo'],
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'projects',
        loadChildren: 'app/...#ProjectsBModule',
        canLoad: [PluginGuard],
        data: {
          requiredPlugins: ['bar'],
        },
      },
```

`PluginGuard` is a simple guard that calls the server to check the value of a field named plugin.

By design, both of these routes cannot load at the same time, as the plugin can only have one value at a given time.

#### Problem

The issue is that only the first entry is taken into account, which means that when plugin has the value `foo`, I can load the module `ProjectsAModule` but when it has the value `bar`, `ProjectsBModule` doesn't load at all, no error message neither.

My guess is that it's because two routes cannot have the same path, at all, but do we have a way to implement this kind of behavior properly? By properly I mean not using a `*ngIf` in a container component to show one component or another base on plugin's value.

Comment: I dont think that you can have 2 separates components under the same path without "hacking" the framework. why dont you put them under same parent, which he is deciding which plugin he should use and redirect accordingly ?

Comment: Angular won't support lazy loading same module with same route. You can keep one module and access the same route (/projects). But you can pass data as query params. In CanLoad AuthGuard, you can use NavigationEnd and read the query param and proceed furthur